# MS Logic Apps: Add File to SharePoint trigger inconsistent

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I have a pre-existing Azure Logic App that is triggered by the addition of a file (When a file is created (properties only)) into a specified SharePoint directory
This worked fine for several months & still works for me
However, I have a user where the app (frequently) isn't triggered at all even though I can see the new file in the folder they've alerted me to

I've cloned the app, enabled the copy & disabled the original as a form of 'switch off/on' but to no effect

The user has trialed a number of different 'file add' methods, through mapped drive, direct through MS 365 on browser, OneDrive but all with the same patchy triggering

Does anybody have suggestions of a cause or an avenue to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, please try to add another file which its name never existed in your sharepoint. If you have already created a file name "test.txt", and remove this file, then create another file with the same name "test.txt". And if the operations in one triggering cycle of the logic app trigger, it may not trigger the logic app. And also please try to create a new logic app with the trigger, test if it can be triggered. Apart from this, how did you check if the logic app be triggered ? Please go to azure portal and take a look the run history of your logic app, but not check the logic app trigger by if receive email from the logic app or any other ways.

By the way, as this problem is not easy for us to investigate, so I suggest you to raise a support ticket on azure portal by following the steps on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request). Maybe there is a bug in this trigger, azure support team can see more logs of your logic and will help you on it.

Comment: Hury, thanks for your response.  This logic app worked for several months previously so its internal logic should be ok.  We use this SP directory for doc storage only, there's no edit management so people aren't checking out/in so very rare for files to have same name.  My previous error checking used run history so I'm comfortable with this.  My problem is, for one user, there's 'sometimes' no run history.  Your suggestion of raising an azure portal ticket may be best if there're extra logs they can review.  Do I need a support agreement for this?  Thanks again Piers

Comment: @PiersS Yes, you need a support plan, you can refer to this [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/).